# move all files on directory to new subdirectory in same directory

Tags: bash-scripting

Please how to move all files on directory to new subdirectory in same directory ?

Like this:

```
/volume1/TEST/file1.jpg to /Volume1/TEST/_NEW_FOLDER/file.jpg
/volume1/TEST2/file2.bmp to /Volume1/TEST2/_NEW_FOLDER/file2.bmp
/volume1/TEST3/file3.dwg to /Volume1/TEST3/_NEW_FOLDER/file3.dwg
/volume1/TEST4/file4.(*) to /Volume1/TEST4/_NEW_FOLDER/file4.(*)
```

Comment: (1) Which operating system? (2) Are you asking for non-interactive way only? (script?)

Comment: Hello, i need basch script (LINUX) from non interactive... this is second script from crond manager ( scheduler ) | Ahoj, potřeboval bych script pro Linux který by měl běžet jako druhý v řadě pro Crond Manager,, prvním skriptem je :RSYNC (rsync -r --log-file=/volume1/TEST/1.log --compare-dest /volume1001/TEST_2/ /volume1/TEST/ALL  /volume1/Processing/_Compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find BaseFolder -mindepth 1 -type f | while read path; do \
dest="$(dirname "$path")/NewFolder"; mkdir "$dest"; mv "$path" "$dest"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

#### New answer

From the command line, you can do it like that:

```
for dir in /volume1/TEST* ; do cd "$dir" ; mkdir _NEW_FOLDER ; mv *.* _NEW_FOLDER ; done
```

Or write a script like that

```
#!/bin/bash
NFLDR=_NEW_FOLDER
for dir in /volume1/TEST*; do (
# for logging to syslog in a cron job, uncomment the following line
# logger moving contents of $dir to $dir/$NEWFLDR
        cd "$dir" && mkdir $NFLDR && mv *.* $NFLDR
); done
# logger moving to subfolders finished
```

then

```
chmod +x mvtosubfolders.sh
./mvtosubfolders.sh
```

Edit: if you want to use that via `cron`, save the script as e. g. `/usr/local/bin/mvtosubfolders.sh` and make executable. Adjust your crontab to invoke `/usr/local/bin/mvtosubfolders.sh` regularly. E. g.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  0 5   *   *   1    /usr/local/bin/mvtosubfolders.sh
```

Example output for the command line:

```
root@router ~/testfolder # tree
.
├── TEST1
│   └── file1.jpg
├── TEST2
│   └── file2.bmp
├── TEST3
│   └── file3.dwg
└── TEST4
    ├── file4.avi
    ├── file4.cr2
    ├── file4.mov
    └── file4.tif

4 directories, 7 files
root@router ~/testfolder # for dir in /root/testfolder/TEST* ; do cd "$dir" ; mkdir _NEW_FOLDER ; mv *.* _NEW_FOLDER ; done
root@router ~/testfolder/TEST4 # cd ..
root@router ~/testfolder # tree
.
├── TEST1
│   └── _NEW_FOLDER
│       └── file1.jpg
├── TEST2
│   └── _NEW_FOLDER
│       └── file2.bmp
├── TEST3
│   └── _NEW_FOLDER
│       └── file3.dwg
└── TEST4
    └── _NEW_FOLDER
        ├── file4.avi
        ├── file4.cr2
        ├── file4.mov
        └── file4.tif

8 directories, 7 files
root@router ~/testfolder #
```

#### Old, wrong answer

Not taking the subfolders into account

Assuming that your files have that dot between file name and extension, just as in your example above: `mv *.* _NEW_FOLDER`

```
root@router ~/testfolder # touch file{1,2,3,4,5}.jgp
root@router ~/testfolder # mkdir subfolder
root@router ~/testfolder # ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:58 .
drwx------ 24 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:58 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file1.jgp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file2.jgp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file3.jgp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file4.jgp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file5.jgp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:58 subfolder
root@router ~/testfolder # mv *.* subfolder
root@router ~/testfolder # ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:59 .
drwx------ 24 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:59 subfolder
root@router ~/testfolder # ls -al subfolder
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 18 09:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file1.jgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file2.jgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file3.jgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file4.jgp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 18 09:58 file5.jgp
```

Comment: thank you it works, and when I do not know how subfolder called? when I have a folder in another folder so it ignores the script, executions knows in advance how many there Create the folder and do not even know what will be the future structure of how many subdirectories.

Comment: In your example, there are two layers of subfolders. `TEST{1..4}` and `_NEW_FOLDER`. Which one are you referring now when you say "don't know how the subfolder is called"? Do you not know `TEST1` or do you not know `_NEW_FOLDER`? If you do not know the name of the folder, can you be sure that it is the _only_ folder?

Comment: Test folder was only mentioned as an example of my problem, the truth is that the unknown tree, do not know if the folder is the only part of this component and thus test {1,2,3,4} is via rsync help difference making change and this change need to return to the original folder to the new folder as change. (_NEW_FOLDER)

Comment: OK. Let's sort that. The original goal in your original question (moving files to subfolders) was achieved. Now there is a new goal concerning a new tool (rsync). Could you please detail exactly what you want to do (in the comments or, better, in your original question). `rsync`is a tool to copy data from A to B. Please let us know which data you want to copy from where to where, and we might find a solution for that, too. ;) -- or ask a new question since you just accepted an answer to this one.

Comment: 1.First
rsync -r --log-file=/volume1/TEST/1.log  --compare-dest /volume1001/TEST_2/ /volume1/TEST/TEST_2  /volume1/Diference/_Compare

1.a ( What is moreover delete in /volume1/TEST/TEST_2)

2.Second
find /volume1/Diference/_Compare -mindepth 1 -type f | while read path; do \
dest="$(dirname "$path")/NewFolder"; mkdir "$dest"; mv "$path" "$dest"; done

3. Move /volume1/Diference/_Compare to /volume1/TEST/TEST_2)

4. ( Finaly) What I Can :
saves any user data ( differential data compared to data in the Backup folder to move to verify the user's permission Correctors

Comment: 1.First
 rsync -r --log-file=/volume1/TEST/1.log  --compare-dest /volume1001/TEST_2/ /volume1/TEST/TEST_2  /volume1/Diference/_Compare
1.a ( What is moreover delete in /volume1/TEST/TEST_2)
2.Second
find /volume1/Diference/_Compare -mindepth 1 -type f | while read path; do \
dest="$(dirname "$path")/NewFolder"; mkdir "$dest"; mv "$path" "$dest"; done
3. Move /volume1/Diference/_Compare to /volume1001/TEST_2/
4. rsync ( copy all /volume1001/TEST_2/ to /volume1/TEST/TEST_2) 
5.verify the user's Correctors

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you use forward slashes, I'll assume a unix derivative:

```
cd /volume1/
for I in TEST*; do mkdir $I/_NEW_FOLDER; mv $I/* $I/_NEW_FOLDER; done
```

Note that this will error when it tries to move the `_NEW_FOLDER` into itself, but it will still work.